# Sum column values if they share the same identifier . (Group by function)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, that has stock 'tickers' that are duplicated and then two columns which have summable columns.

[original DF]

[image: 1]

My aim is to get only unique 'tickers' with the sum of those tickers for the two additional columns.

The code I am trying to use is :

```
dfA.groupby(['Ticker']).sum()
```

but the error I am getting is :

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

[Error msg]

[image: 2]

Comment: you must provide a reproducible example (code and data that can run to reproduce the issue), not images. Also I find it weird that this error is caused by a `groupby.sum`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.